# INSTALL_FAILED_DEXOPT on Gingerbeard(2.3.7)

Tags: android, installation, failed-installation

Not able to identify cause for INSTALL_FAILED_DEXOPT .

This issue is coming only on 2.3.7 devices. on rest of the devices, its working fine.

Answer (score 1):

An application you're building probably is getting larger and now it has too big .dex file.

1) Try to remove unused code using ProGuard:
https://developer.android.com/tools/help/proguard.html

2) As another option you can start using Multidex support:
https://developer.android.com/tools/building/multidex.html

Comment: But the point is i have same base code with different package, that one is working fine. i have also tried with removing external jars one by one. Still nothing new.

Comment: Anyway, have you ever tried to configure ProGuard? If not, then it is time to try.

Comment: Already tried, while exporting an apk, got an error named - Conversion to dalvik failed with error 1